# Update only if entry does not exist

Tags: mysql, update

I have to update many records. I don't want to duplicate the entries.  The table concatenates the value to the end.  So in theory, I could add the value twice.

I want to put a check to make sure the entry is not already there; if it is, then skip the record.

```
update table1 
set value=concat(value,',test_data') 
where field1='abc';
```

Comment: Fix the [list of doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html) and these sort of questions will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table1 
SET value=CONCAT(value, ',test_data') 
WHERE field1='abc'
  AND NOT INSTR(CONCAT(',',value,','), ',test_data,');
```

But I'd recommend to normalize your data structure... CSV data field is not safe.

Comment: Fails to handle start and end of string.  Switch to `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: @RickJames ??? why?